# ExtJs: which layout to choose for complex form with many fields

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs3

I need to implement a big complex form in extjs. 
This form contains about 20 lines with  5-6 fields on each line. There are textfields, combos and just displayfields in these lines.

I implemented it with 'form' layout for the parent panel. And with 'hbox' layout panels for each line. In order to display field labels, I have to wrap each field into a panel with form layout again. 
It even sounds scary, could you imaging this mess? I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

Need an advice on how to do it in a right way!

Updated: please check an example of layout I'm trying to get.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use `layout: 'column'` quite a bit. Then you can tell each field how much of a `columnWidth`  each one should have. When the widths add up to over 1, the fields wrap to the next line.

For your screenshot, all of them are a column width of a third, so you could do something like this:

```
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'column',
    defaults: {columnWidth: 0.3},
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield'
    },{
       ...
    }]
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wrapping each row in `panel` you can use built-in [`FieldContainer`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer) widget (extjs4) or `Ext.form.CompositeField` widget (extjs3).

Comment: good idea, but I'm using ExtJs3. Does it have something similar?

Comment: @innerJL, yes, of course it has. Check out `Ext.form.CompositeField` widget.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't suit. For example typical row looks like:

checkbox it's label textfield (with label right above textfield) one more textfield

It is impossible to create this with compositefield, the biggest issue is to place fields labels as I need.

Comment: @innerJL, could you post screenshot of current layout so I could find out how exactly it should look?

Comment: please see below, I added snap shot.

Comment: @innerJL, your approach is the best for this layout, I think. The only thing I can suggest is to use `Ext.Container` instead of `Ext.Panel`. It has not unnecesary extra features like toolbars,headers, and so on, but is supports basic layouts.